# Why from a virtualized Ubuntu system I can't discover the ip address of my router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vmware, nat

I am not into computer network and I have the following problem finding my router IP address.

I have a Windows 8 PC on on which it is installed VmWare Workstation that virtualizes Linux Ubuntu.

The **network adapter** settings of this Virtual Machine is setted as **NAT**.

Now my problem is that if in the Windows 8 DOS shell I perform the **ifconfig** statment I obtain

```
C:\Users\Andrea>ipconfig

Configurazione IP di Windows


Scheda Ethernet tap0:

   Stato supporto. . . . . . . . . . . . : Supporto disconnesso
   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione: techub.lan

Scheda Ethernet Connessione di rete Bluetooth:

   Stato supporto. . . . . . . . . . . . : Supporto disconnesso
   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:

Scheda LAN wireless Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)* 11:

   Stato supporto. . . . . . . . . . . . : Supporto disconnesso
   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:

Scheda LAN wireless Wi-Fi:

   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione: DSL2750B
   Indirizzo IPv6 locale rispetto al collegamento . : fe80::89ff:6d12:49cf:4354%13
   Indirizzo IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
   Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Gateway predefinito . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Scheda Ethernet Ethernet:

   Stato supporto. . . . . . . . . . . . : Supporto disconnesso
   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:

Scheda Ethernet VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:
   Indirizzo IPv6 locale rispetto al collegamento . : fe80::edb3:8352:f954:2b0c%23
   Indirizzo IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.129.1
   Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Gateway predefinito . . . . . . . . . :

Scheda Ethernet VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:
   Indirizzo IPv6 locale rispetto al collegamento . : fe80::d00b:8c6e:98b:f1ec%24
   Indirizzo IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.15.1
   Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Gateway predefinito . . . . . . . . . :

Scheda Tunnel Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Stato supporto. . . . . . . . . . . . : Supporto disconnesso
   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:

Scheda Tunnel isatap.techub.lan:

   Stato supporto. . . . . . . . . . . . : Supporto disconnesso
   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione: techub.lan

Scheda Tunnel isatap.{5B95051D-79AB-4147-92CF-3A2E16698432}:

   Stato supporto. . . . . . . . . . . . : Supporto disconnesso
   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:

Scheda Tunnel isatap.{340A5FAD-1597-402E-B658-29C37E8F7BC2}:

   Stato supporto. . . . . . . . . . . . : Supporto disconnesso
   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:

Scheda Tunnel isatap.DSL2750B:

   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione: DSL2750B
   Indirizzo IPv6 locale rispetto al collegamento . : fe80::5efe:192.168.1.3%26
   Gateway predefinito . . . . . . . . . :
```

So, looking at the previous output it appear clear that the **default gateway** (my router) is: **192.168.1.1**, infact if I open it into a browser it apear to me the login mask to enter in the router settings....

Ok, if now I open the virtualized Ubuntu shell and perform the **route** command I obtain this output:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~$ route
Tabella di routing IP del kernel
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.15.2    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.15.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

So, here it say to me that the **default gateway** is **192.168.15.2** (that is not my router ip address), why?

My idea is that it could depend by the NAT. Because my Windows system is connected using the wireless but in the virtualized Ubuntu I see that I am connected to a "wired network".

So I think that the NAT virtualize a **network adapter** (or something like this) and that **192.168.15.2** could be the ip address of this network adapter...

But it seems strange to me because, as you can see in the previous **ipconfig** output the VmWare network adapter addresses are: **192.168.129.1** and **192.168.15.1**.

So I have also 2 others doubts:

1) What device represents the **192.168.15.2** ip address that the virtualized Ubuntu see as **Default gateway** but that is not my router?

2) What exactly do the two VmWare network adapter that I have configured into my Windows 8 system?

There is a way to discover my router ip from the virtualized Ubuntu system ?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, of course this happens because your VM is NATted. You can discover your router address, in Ubuntu, by typing:

```
 $ ip route show
 default via 192.168.73.1 dev eth0  proto static 
 192.168.73.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.73.88  metric 1
```

where my machine replies that my gateway is 192.168.73.1. If you were to do the same on your Ubuntu, you would discover that your gateway is 192.168.15.1.

192.168.15.2 is instead the IP address of your (virtualized) NIC inside the VM: you can check this by means of the command

```
 ip addr show
```

You will find your eth0 NIC has an IP address of 192.168.15.2

Virtualization networking works this way: two (virtualized) NICs are created, one on host the other one on guest, and assigned IP numbers outside the range normally provided by home LANs (in your case 192.168.15.0 instead of the more common 192.168.0.0 or 192.168.1.0). On your VM, you set 192.168.15.1 as the gateway, and the host OS is responsible for routing what comes out of the virtualied NIC to the physical NIC, and from there on to your home router. Thus the VMWare NIC (or adapter, whatever) with IP address 192.168.15.1 thus acts as a gateway fro your VM: it is essential for networking the VM.

The other adapter could be one of two things: the gateway of another NIC on your VM (in line of principle, you can have as many as you want, the command *ip addr show* will help you to establish whether this is indeed the case) or a leftover from a previous instance of VMWare.

Lastly, no, there is no **local** way to discover the IP address of your home router from a NATted VM. This is identical to knowing what the IP address of the WAN side of your router is: unless you log into your router, you will never be able to learn it from inside your home LAN.

There is an alternative to NAT connection for VMs, which is called a **bridged** connection. In this case, your VM is directly linked to your home LAN, and receives an IP address directly from your router. In this configuration, the gateway which you discover through the command

```
 ip route show
```

will be your home router.